# How to use jQuery in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

Hi I'm new to JSF and jQuery .
Do I need to download any jQuery jar and pack to war in order to use?
Because in my code I can't call the jquery function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

  <h:head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/06.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#form\\:name").click(function() {
         alert("hii");
      });
   });
 </script>

 </h:head>
 <h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
      <h:outputText id="hi" value="hi guys"></h:outputText>
      <input id="name" />
    </h:form>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

This alert doesn't popup when I click on the output box.

In my pom I use this dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.efsavage.jquery</groupId>
   <artifactId>jquery-maven</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as in another web applications, jsf tags support onclick attribute also.
please download my jsf-frontend fully configured web applications(JSF2.2+Primefaces+JQuery) and test on it.
[Here is a link, JSF2.2 front end](https://github.com/armdev/jsf-frontend)

One note: Primefaces also used Jquery and you can use it, or you can skip and include your jquery.
In my project you can find header files whit configuration.

Also good example here [How to get JSF id via jQuery](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-get-jsf-id-via-jquery/)
Good luck!

Comment: Actually my question is Do I need to include Jquery jar files into POM file or not? If yes. What jar files I should include and How Do I refer them in the  <script>  tags.